# In CONTEXT, how can I get the total number of chapters?

Tags: context, counters, context-mkiv

For total number of **pages**, one can use `\lastcounter[userpage]` to get the total number of pages in the document.  Actually it gives the number on the last page (which is more interesting).  Similar commands work for the total number of formulas, figures, etc. in the document.

How can I get the number of **chapters**?  Inspecting `structures.counters` in Lua doesn't show a counter associated with chapter numbering.

Here is my use case in particular: I have *sections* and *subsections* and I have arranged for the numbering of the latter not to get reset at each new section.  I want to have the total number of subsections in my document: "5" in the example below.

```
Section 1
  Subsection 1
  Subsection 2
Section 2
  Subsection 3
  Subsection 4
  Subsection 5
```

The command `\somenamedheadnumber{subsection}{last}` provides the last subsection number within the currently active structure (current section in my case), but I could not find a way to get the very last value for the entire document.

In TeX/LaTeX I would add a hook to `\subsection` to log the counter value to a file and then read that file at the beginning of the document to compute the final value.  (This simplifies a bit if one uses `\AtEndDocument` in LaTeX.)  I'm sure there is a simple way to do this in CONTEXT but I could not find it.

Comment: \AtEndDocument is for LaTeX.  My question is about ConTeXt.  I'm looking for a simple way to achieve this in ConTeXt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command [\determinelistcharacteristics](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/determinelistcharacteristics) and then `\structurelistsize` to access the value. Example:

```
\starttext

\determinelistcharacteristics
  [chapter]
  [criterium=text]

number of chapters: \structurelistsize

\startsectionlevel [title=Foo]
  \startsectionlevel [title=title 1] section 1 \stopsectionlevel
  \startsectionlevel [title=title 2] section 2 \stopsectionlevel
\stopsectionlevel

\startsectionlevel [title=Bar]
  \startsectionlevel [title=title 3] section 3 \stopsectionlevel
  \startsectionlevel [title=title 4] section 4 \stopsectionlevel
\stopsectionlevel

\stoptext
```

Replace the first argument of `\determinelistcharacteristics` with `section`, `subsection` or any other section level to obtain the other section levels' counters.

The `criterium=text` is required in case the `\determinelistcharacteristics` command follows the sections instead of preceding them. Without setting the criterium, the value of `\structurelistsize` would be wrong.

Comment: What is the purpose of the "criterium= text" in your example?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer To obtain correct values for `\structurelistsize` in case the `\determinelistcharacteristics` is placed *after* the sections. See edit.

Comment: I'm not getting it. If I move the `\determinlistcharacteristics` behind a `\startsection..` I get the wrong number of chapter (0) with and without the criterium. Also what does "text" mean? The part between \starttext and \stoptext?

Comment: How efficient is the macro `\determinelistcharacteristics`?  Should I use it as part of setting the footers in my presentation or is it better to use an `\xdef`?  Though the latter works with your code snippet, it produces a value of zero in my presentation.  I will try to create a minimal non-working example when I get a chance.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer [See the example of how the `text` key affects the output](http://dpaste.com/09R7AFF). `text` is a standard key for `criterium`, I don't know why it was chosen and what it refers to.

Comment: But you moved the \structurelistsize too ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I probably don't get your question or don't see the problem for whatever reason. Find an example that fails for you and approach the mailing list. Hans and Wolfgang can answer those details much better than I possibly could.

Comment: @MHB Use the command `\testfeatureonce` to run a small benchmark. I don't think the additional runtime matters at all, but your documents might be different.

Comment: I did a benchmark and on my machine every invocation of the two macros takes less than 0.05ms, so no efficiency problem at all.